# Joomla: Why is the “Extension Manager” menu item not showing in the “Extensions” drop down menu?

Tags: php, database, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.4

As per the title. I am running Joomla 3.4.5

The only items visible in the "Extensions" drop down menu are:

- Modules
- Plug-ins
- Templates
- Languages

I am doing this for the purpose of installing a template.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are logged in as super user (most likely you are not).